# Why is the data from firebase not getting displayed in my text views?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I had posted questions on firebase realtime database as a json array of questions and tried to retrieve it from the firebase to my app but i am getting to see same text in my text views as I had set as default in my xml file so please help
My database is a json array containing a class Questions , in that there are five categories and each category has 9 question fields which has six sections ; the question,four options and correct answer (all strings)

```
public class Questions extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseReference dref;
DatabaseReference ref,ques;
TextView question,option1,option2,option3,option4;
ImageButton imageButton;

int val,correct,wrong,score;

public Questions() {
    this.val = 0;
    this.correct=0;
    this.wrong=0;
    this.score=0;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_questions);
    question=findViewById(R.id.question);
    imageButton=findViewById(R.id.next);
    option1=findViewById(R.id.opt1);
    option2=findViewById(R.id.opt2);
    option3=findViewById(R.id.opt3);
    option4=findViewById(R.id.opt4);
    dref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    Integer value=intent.getIntExtra("type",0);
   switch (value)
   {
       case 1:
           ref=dref.child("Questions").child("Bollywood");

            break;
       case 2:
           ref=dref.child("Questions").child("Sports");
           break;
       case 3:
           ref=dref.child("Questions").child("Technology");
           break;
       case 4:
           ref=dref.child("Questions").child("Entertainment");
           break;
       case 5:
           ref=dref.child("Questions").child("Miscellaneous");
           break;
           default:
               break;
   }
    ques = ref.child(String.valueOf(val));
    ques.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            QAnswer qAnswer=dataSnapshot.getValue(QAnswer.class);
            question.setText(qAnswer.getQuestion());
            option1.setText(qAnswer.getOption1());
            option2.setText(qAnswer.getOption2());
            option3.setText(qAnswer.getOption3());
            option4.setText(qAnswer.getOption4());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
   imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           if(val>15)
           {

           }
           else {
               ques = ref.child(String.valueOf(++val));
               ques.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                       final QAnswer qAnswer=dataSnapshot.getValue(QAnswer.class);
                       Log.d("value",qAnswer.getQuestion()+qAnswer.getAnswer());
                       question.setText(qAnswer.getQuestion());
                       option1.setText(qAnswer.getOption1());
                       option2.setText(qAnswer.getOption2());
                       option3.setText(qAnswer.getOption3());
                       option4.setText(qAnswer.getOption4());
                       option1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onClick(View v) {
                               if(qAnswer.getOption1()==qAnswer.getAnswer())
                               {
                                   option1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                                   correct++;
                               }
                               else {
                                   option1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                                   wrong++;

                               }
                           }
                       });
                       option2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onClick(View v) {

                           }
                       });
                       option3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onClick(View v) {

                           }
                       });
                       option4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onClick(View v) {

                           }
                       });
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                   }
               });

           }
       }
   });


}
}
```

This is my questions model class:

```
public class QAnswer {
String question;
String option1;
String option2;
String option3;
String option4;
String answer;

public QAnswer(String question, String option1, String option2, String option3, String option4, String answer) {
    this.question = question;
    this.option1 = option1;
    this.option2 = option2;
    this.option3 = option3;
    this.option4 = option4;
    this.answer = answer;
}

public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}

public String getOption1() {
    return option1;
}

public void setOption1(String option1) {
    this.option1 = option1;
}

public String getOption2() {
    return option2;
}

public void setOption2(String option2) {
    this.option2 = option2;
}

public String getOption3() {
    return option3;
}

public void setOption3(String option3) {
    this.option3 = option3;
}

public String getOption4() {
    return option4;
}

public void setOption4(String option4) {
    this.option4 = option4;
}

public String getAnswer() {
    return answer;
}

public void setAnswer(String answer) {
    this.answer = answer;
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your questions model class

```
public QAnswer(){
}
```

before this

```
public QAnswer(String question, String option1, String option2, String option3, String option4, String answer) {
    this.question = question;
    this.option1 = option1;
    this.option2 = option2;
    this.option3 = option3;
    this.option4 = option4;
    this.answer = answer;
}
```